# Blockscout Hardhat "Unable to find a block containing transaction"

Tags: hardhat, blockscout

I had Hardhat node running and then started up Blockscout from docker-compose (`hardhat-network.yml`) and all seemed to be ok.

I made some config changes to hardhat as I'm attempting to verify contracts on the hardhat network.  Then I restarted the hardhat node.

Soon the console running the hardhat node (ie. console.log) started filling with these for example.  It is 6 transactions over and over.  But not uniformly.

I am quite certain the log messages weren't occurring before the restart.

```
debug_traceTransaction

  Unable to find a block containing transaction 0xf0843a1a617a6c2b670508c81bd0c2123de57493a6352211fd5bf250f866cf2f

debug_traceTransaction

  Unable to find a block containing transaction 0x4ebd04d62bdb384f61a6a2d08fdbdceb441e6b976bae01e845987ad34b774a6b

debug_traceTransaction

  Unable to find a block containing transaction 0x06a63101cdb516b4fab23acbbb9f6585fc22e6e51cde42c388417c27cd188878

debug_traceTransaction

  Unable to find a block containing transaction 0x4111eef31bc23dfe6eb2d553eee4aba8194b6300231ef11a6fc5dc278b262bc4

debug_traceTransaction

  Unable to find a block containing transaction 0x817f6c545c3ad6aeed7f1119c3741a99d6d8699817ccd1439e012a7b44a8e858

debug_traceTransaction

  Unable to find a block containing transaction 0x06a63101cdb516b4fab23acbbb9f6585fc22e6e51cde42c388417c27cd188878
```

When I kill the blockscout docker-compose those debug messages stop.

The Blockscout logs contain the same 'unable to find block containing transaction' error:

```
2024-01-25 12:01:57 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T01:01:57.499Z","severity":"error","message":"failed to fetch internal transactions for blocks: ** (ErlangError) Erlang error: [%{code: -32000, data: %{block_number: 52, transaction_hash: \"0x06a63101cdb516b4fab23acbbb9f6585fc22e6e51cde42c388417c27cd188878\", transaction_index: 0}, message: \"Unable to find a block containing transaction 0x06a63101cdb516b4fab23acbbb9f6585fc22e6e51cde42c388417c27cd188878\"}]","metadata":{"count":10,"error_count":10,"fetcher":"internal_transaction"}}
2024-01-25 12:01:57 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T01:01:57.499Z","severity":"error","message":"failed to fetch internal transactions for blocks: ** (ErlangError) Erlang error: [%{code: -32000, data: %{block_number: 51, transaction_hash: \"0x4ebd04d62bdb384f61a6a2d08fdbdceb441e6b976bae01e845987ad34b774a6b\", transaction_index: 0}, message: \"Unable to find a block containing transaction 0x4ebd04d62bdb384f61a6a2d08fdbdceb441e6b976bae01e845987ad34b774a6b\"}]","metadata":{"count":10,"error_count":10,"fetcher":"internal_transaction"}}
2024-01-25 12:01:57 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T01:01:57.501Z","severity":"error","message":"failed to fetch internal transactions for blocks: ** (ErlangError) Erlang error: [%{code: -32000, data: %{block_number: 31, transaction_hash: \"0xf0843a1a617a6c2b670508c81bd0c2123de57493a6352211fd5bf250f866cf2f\", transaction_index: 0}, message: \"Unable to find a block containing transaction 0xf0843a1a617a6c2b670508c81bd0c2123de57493a6352211fd5bf250f866cf2f\"}]","metadata":{"count":10,"error_count":10,"fetcher":"internal_transaction"}}
2024-01-25 12:01:57 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T01:01:57.505Z","severity":"error","message":"failed to fetch internal transactions for blocks: ** (ErlangError) Erlang error: [%{code: -32000, data: %{block_number: 41, transaction_hash: \"0x4111eef31bc23dfe6eb2d553eee4aba8194b6300231ef11a6fc5dc278b262bc4\", transaction_index: 0}, message: \"Unable to find a block containing transaction 0x4111eef31bc23dfe6eb2d553eee4aba8194b6300231ef11a6fc5dc278b262bc4\"}]","metadata":{"count":9,"error_count":9,"fetcher":"internal_transaction"}}
2024-01-25 12:01:57 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T01:01:57.508Z","severity":"info","message":"Index had to catch up.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup","first_block_number":1,"last_block_number":1,"missing_block_count":1,"shrunk":false}}
```

There are a few errors in the log proceeding this. And of course there are lots of `info`s and the occassional `warn` (that doesn't seem to be related - eg locked mutex that is soon unlocked).  The errors are:

```
2024-01-25 12:32:03 proxy           | 2024/01/25 01:32:03 [error] 38#38: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.65.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /socket/v2/websocket?vsn=2.0.0 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.23.0.5:4000/socket/v2/websocket?vsn=2.0.0", host: "localhost"
2024-01-25 12:32:03 proxy           | 192.168.65.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:01:32:03 +0000] "GET /socket/v2/websocket?vsn=2.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

The frontend seems to be ok and is displaying correct data.

Those 6 transactions all exist and can be seen in Blockscout frontend.  They are not all on the same block, they are not adjacent to each other.

Now, doesn't the top-level Blockscout > Blockchain > Transactions only show external transactions?  Yet the error message is that these internal tx can't be found.  Is that a clue?

Does anyone know what this is occurring and how I can make it stop?

---

Approx 90 mins later

The frontend has stopped working erroring with 'something went wrong' and this is occurring every 12 to 13 seconds, and the docker console shows the backend restarting:

```
...
2024-01-25 15:34:38 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T04:34:38.929Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4246.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4569.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
2024-01-25 15:34:38 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T04:34:38.927Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4222.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4569.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
2024-01-25 15:34:38 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T04:34:38.957Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4211.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4569.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
2024-01-25 15:34:41 backend         | {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_terminated,indexer,shutdown}"}
2024-01-25 15:34:41 backend         | Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_terminated,indexer,shutdown})
2024-01-25 15:34:41 backend         | 
2024-01-25 15:34:41 backend         | Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
2024-01-25 15:34:45 backend         | warning: redefining module ConfigHelper (current version defined in memory)
2024-01-25 15:34:45 backend         |   config/config_helper.exs:1
2024-01-25 15:34:45 backend         | 
2024-01-25 15:34:45 backend         | warning: redefining module ConfigHelper (current version defined in memory)
2024-01-25 15:34:45 backend         |   config/config_helper.exs:1
2024-01-25 15:34:45 backend         | 
2024-01-25 15:34:45 backend         | Starting dependencies..
2024-01-25 15:34:46 backend         | Starting repos..
2024-01-25 15:34:46 backend         | Create Explorer.Repo database if it doesn't exist
2024-01-25 15:34:46 backend         | Create Explorer.Repo.Account database if it doesn't exist
2024-01-25 15:34:46 backend         | Running migrations for explorer
2024-01-25 15:34:46 backend         | Running migrations for explorer
2024-01-25 15:34:46 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T04:34:46.419Z","severity":"info","message":"Migrations already up","metadata":{}}
2024-01-25 15:34:46 backend         | Success!
2024-01-25 15:34:46 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T04:34:46.441Z","severity":"info","message":"Migrations already up","metadata":{}}
2024-01-25 15:34:53 backend         | warning: redefining module ConfigHelper (current version defined in memory)
2024-01-25 15:34:53 backend         |   config/config_helper.exs:1
2024-01-25 15:34:53 backend         | 
2024-01-25 15:34:53 backend         | warning: redefining module ConfigHelper (current version defined in memory)
2024-01-25 15:34:53 backend         |   config/config_helper.exs:1
2024-01-25 15:34:53 backend         | 
2024-01-25 15:34:54 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T04:34:54.065Z","severity":"info","message":"[Que] Booting Que","metadata":{}}
2024-01-25 15:34:54 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T04:34:54.066Z","severity":"info","message":"[Que] Booting Server Supervisor for Workers","metadata":{}}
2024-01-25 15:34:54 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T04:34:54.155Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
2024-01-25 15:34:54 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T04:34:54.155Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: earliest date 2024-01-16 00:00:00Z","metadata":{}}
2024-01-25 15:34:54 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T04:34:54.155Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: latest date 2024-01-16 23:59:59Z","metadata":{}}
2024-01-25 15:34:54 backend         | {"time":"2024-01-25T04:34:54.393Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: timestamp cannot be converted to min/max blocks, trying to find min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
...
```

<s>Now, even after restarting the container the 'something went wrong' error still occurring.  The logs don't show any related error messages in FrontEnd.</s>

Sorry, my bad I stopped the hardhat node.

Comment: I have started the conversation with the Hardhat people (@nomicfoundation) and will report back here with any conclusions.  https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/discussions/4796